# my django admin page don't have the css when viewed over the apache server

Tags: html, css, django, apache, apache2

I just finished to serve my pages on the internet through apache. I can see my webpage nicely, but when I try the admin, the django admin page don't have the css with it, just the html page. But my webpage's css are displaying nicely.
Thank you!

my http.conf snippet:

```
WSGIPythonPath C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc

<Directory C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

#Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt
#Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc/static/styles/$1

#Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc/static/

<Directory C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

#<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
#Order deny,allow
#Allow from all
#</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc/etc/wsgi.py

<Directory C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc/etc>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

my settings snippet:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/robin/web/etc/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have made a different directory for the static, and have already directed django to the dir where to find static. I have edited and added  the setting's snippet above, kindly check it. And have run the `collectstatic` command, and it has created three directories - admin, css and images. And copied all the statics from the project to that directory, even the admin's css and images in the admin dir. And the server is also displaying my project's css nicely. But not of the admin's css. What am I missing? Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each application has own static files (generally in 'static' directory, but not necessarily, see [settings.STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_FINDERS)). Django serves this files in debug mode, but before deploy to real server you must collect all static from all apps, put it into one folder and configure webserver. You can do it manually, or set [settings.STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root) to apache's docroot and run [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) command.

In sum, apache config:

```
Alias /static/ C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc/static/
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/robin/web/etc/etc/static/'
```

And run collectstatic:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: I have made a different directory for the static, and have already directed django to the dir where to find static. I have edited and added  the setting's snippet above, kindly check it. And have run the `collectstatic` command, and it has created three directories - admin, css and images. And copied all the statics from the project to that directory, even the admin's css and images. And the server is also displaying my project's css nicely. But not of the admin's css. Do I have to point the apache to the projects static?

Comment: Try to remove AliasMatch directive from apache config.

Comment: Typo? `Alias /static/ C:/Users/robin/web/*etc/etc*/static/` and `STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/robin/web/etc/static/'`

Answer (score 2):

Tell Django where to find the static files (if you have not already).

First, make sure you have `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` set correctly in `settings.py', and then on your live server simply run the following command.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will collect all static files necessary for the admin to render correctly.

When running the development server (runserver) static files are automatically found using `STATICFILES_FINDERS`, but in production this is not the case, in-fact `STATICFILES_FINDERS` does somethine else in production, it finds and collects the files after `running python manage.py collectstatic ' they are then served in your case by Apache.

Comment: I have made a different directory for the static, and have already directed django to the dir where to find static. I have edited and added  the setting's snippet above, kindly check it. And have run the `collectstatic` command, and it has created three directories - admin, css and images. And copied all the statics from the project to that directory, even the admin's css and images. And the server is also displaying my project's css nicely. But not of the admin's css.